# Firebase Flutter onBackgroundMessage is not invoked

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I want to handle incoming notifications (from Firebase) in the background.
So I provided a method to handle the incoming notification when the app is in the background, as described in the documentation: [text](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive?hl=de#background_messages)

The problem:
Though I can receive messages in the background, the background handler method (firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler) is not invoked for some reason. OnMessage is working as expected. Only tested on IOS so far.

Firebaes intialization and setup:

```
 await Firebase.initializeApp();
 await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission();

 FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
 FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
        (RemoteMessage message) => _firebaseMessagingForgrounHandler(message));
```

Background handler:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print("---------------------On Background Message--------------------");
}
```

Firebase version (pubspec.yaml):

```
#firebase
 firebase_core: ^2.7.1
 firebase_messaging: ^14.2.6
```

Flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.1, on macOS 13.4 22F66 darwin-arm64, locale de-DE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you made the `firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler` a top-level function (e.g. not a class method which requires initialization) ([source](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#background-messages)) ?

Did you take the extra steps to enable background notifications on iOS ? [See here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration#enable-background-modes-ios-only)